# tidesdk very slow, in html documents

Tags: html, performance, tidesdk

I work with tideSDK i am make a document in html with external css but in the app is very slow

please help me!

I work with the php module and javascript

but to make my document cOnly tests. html visualization remains slow in the application created in tideSDK

important:

when I run my project and document in the browser, running normal and fine, without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

TideSDK uses WebKit as underlying technology. You may find some difficulties as the webkit used is quite old. [TideKit](https://www.tidekit.com) is the new technology and the future path for TideSDK users. here is the blog post about the comparison how TideKit would be better than TideSDK https://blog.tidekit.com/post/from-a-desktop-perspective-tidekit-for-tidesdk-developers

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the css code..

the attributes :      box-shadows  and similar attributes, slow generate in the app

try to test your document without or without your css css style sheet and see that it works normally.

removed from your code css attributes of shadows and stuff.